# InfluxDB replace null values with 0

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql

I have some timeseries data for host availability. The issue is that, when the host is down, nothing is sent onto Influx, so the values for these timestamps are `null`.

If I use `fill(0)` when selecting the timeseries data I can get the series data correct.

Can I somehow change the values of `null` to `0` instead of displaying them as `0`?

When I group them for like a month I cannot fill the null values since it is already aggregated...

Comment: Your question `Can I somehow change the values of null to 0 instead of displaying them as 0 ?` has also answer `If I use fill(0) when selecting the timeseries data I can get the series data correct.` So it is hard to understand what is a problem. I would recommend edit/create new question with better problem description.

Comment: @JanGaraj In detail I wanted to find if there is any way of updating automatically values on InfluxDB by querying it. But I've done it manually... Extracting, editing the data and re-importing it.